# What is the symbol in the Infinity War post-credits scene?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In the post-credits scene of Avengers: Infinity War,

> Director Fury sends a signal somewhere but instead of the recipient's name, a logo is displayed on the device instead. It looked like a golden star with golden angular "wings" behind it on a blue and red background. It resembled Captain America's logo but it wouldn't make much sense to send a signal to him at that point. I assume the logo belongs to a Marvel character who will be introduced in a future film.
>  [image: screenshot of the device]

Who does that symbol belong to?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It's a reference to

> [Captain Marvel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Marvel_(film)), whose movie is coming out soon.  Here's her suit: [image: Captain Marvel]

Comment: Also, I guess I just spoiled myself :P

Comment: I applaud you for picking the image where _________ is/are getting ready. That's very fitting for the context.

Answer (score 13):

The logo which was shown in the pager of Nick Fury was the logo of ...

> Captain Marvel.
>
>  [image: Captain Marvel]